# Retrieving JSONP in PHP not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jsonp

I'm pulling my hair off with this issue:
I'm sending some data from a form from one domain to another using JSONP, It works marvelous on my localhost, but is just not working on the server. I'm using CodeIgniter 2.X for the backend. 
Here's some code:

```
 var telefono = $('#telefono').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var mensaje = $('#mensaje').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.example.com/site/admin/index.php/controller/save',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: JSON.stringify({nombre:nombre,telefono:telefono,email:email,mensaje:mensaje,idPropiedad:46}),
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true
        })
```

On CodeIgniter:

```
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_dump($info);
```

That's how I retrieve the data, It works like a charm on my localhost. Yet I get NULL on this server. I also tried dumping the $_POST array, nothing there.

This is what I get dumping the $_GET array:

```
 array(3) {
  ["callback"]=>
  string(42) "jQuery1111037374000856652856_1438207931357"
  ["{\"nombre\":\"fasf\",\"telefono\":\"asfasfasfas\",\"email\":\"asfasfas\",\"mensaje\":\"fasfasfa\",\"idPropiedad\":46}"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["_"]=>
  string(13) "1438207931360"
}
```

I also tried sending the data with FormData() from the frontend, nothing.

This is what's being sent:

```
Request URL:http://www.example.cl/site/admin/index.php/controller/save?callback=jQuery1111037374000856652856_1438207931357&{%22nombre%22:%22fasf%22,%22telefono%22:%22asfasfasfas%22,%22email%22:%22asfasfas%22,%22mensaje%22:%22fasfasfa%22,%22idPropiedad%22:46}&_=1438207931359
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same version of jQuery on both locations?

Comment: Are you sure the path in `$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` is correct? I don't know of any `php://input`...

Comment: `php://input` should work - I use that regularly. Try using `dataType: 'json'` instead and see if that changes anything. `$.ajax` api for 'jsonp' says: "Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true."

Comment: can't do a POST using `jsonp`....that's why your headers are showing `GET`. If you control both domains, you can enable CORS on the other domain or use your server to do post using cURL

Comment: @psalmody I have to use jsonp because the jquery script and the receiver are in different domains. If I use GET as the type, this is what I get dumping the `$_GET`:
`/**/_xdc_._q58197 && _xdc_._q58197( [0,null,1] )`

Comment: did you read all of what I wrote? I gave you the options available to you

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I solved the problem using `cors`, nonetheless I'm still getting nothing on `$_POST` and `$_GET`. I'm using `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: you aren't sending key value/pairs in data, only value. Don't stringify and use $_POST in php

Answer (score 0):

Using `POST` with `jsonp` is a contradiction.  As you can see, `GET` is being used.  The rest of your data is unavailable (well, difficult to access at least) because you stringified it.  If you just pass the unstringified object, jQuery will turn your object into key/value pairs in the URL.

```
var telefono = $('#telefono').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var mensaje = $('#mensaje').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/site/admin/index.php/controller/save',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
       nombre: nombre,
       telefono: telefono,
       email: email,
       mensaje: mensaje,
       idPropiedad: 46
    }
});
```

Then, you can access the data via:

```
$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
$telefono = $_GET['telefono'];
... etc
```

Comment: Yes, that's the logic way to go. Unfortunately, something really weird is going on with either my code or my servers. That's why I had to use `CORS`. Thanks for replying.